# Include partials in hjs

Tags: ejs, hogan.js

In ejs we can include a partials in a template in this way (suppose that header.hjs is in view/partials path):

```
<% include ./partials/header %>
```

How can I do this in hjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [this link](http://code.runnable.com/U1AuhhaNhHRyUBoV/express-and-hogan-partials-and-template-inheritance) (the sample in this link uses layout and partials and I just used partials for my case to include a navBar):

The solution is:

1. Add your partial in views (e.g views\navBarPartial.hjs).
2. In app.js (server.js) define the partial:

   app.set('partials',
     {
       navBarPartial: 'navBarPartial'
     }
   );
3. In the view which you need this partial, include it:

```html
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
    ...
    {{> navBarPartial}}
    ...
</body>
</html>
```